# Reading from the nasa feed rss file throws SAXException

Tags: android, inputstream, saxparser, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to use the simple-framework in android to read a file which I take from the nasa feed.
The nasa file is here:
http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss

The way I go around this is by using the following code:

```
Serializer serialezr = new Persister();



        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/nasa";
        try{
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if(!dir.exists())
            {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File nasa = new File(file_path,filename);
            if(nasa.exists())
            {
                nasa.delete();
            }
            nasa.createNewFile();
            source = new File(file_path + "/" + filename);


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);

            view.setText(sw.toString() + "here");
        }
```

The above code creates the nasa.xml file in a directory which I will later use

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");
            }



            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(source,total.toString());
```

The above code actually gets the file from their website using a DefaultHttpClient.

"Googling" this I have discovered that the xml file might not be written properly? Looking at the xml file from nasa I cannot see any "<>" tags which appeared to be the most common error that throws this exception.

**UPDATES**

- Instead of using BufferedReader and appending a line after a line I 
  have used InputStreamReader to read each character. It runs out of 
  memory
- Looks like if I take out the ImageView from the layout everything works even the xml parsing.

Comment: I looked at the xml file and don't see anything wrong.  It has encoded html in it (like &lt; for <).  Where do you get the error?

Comment: @RickFalck thanks for your comment. I cannot see an actual line number but from what I can distinguish it's saying this : "position: START_TAG < J

Comment: What is the last start tag it gets too?

Comment: @RickFalck not sure what you mean. But the last element it reads is <title> of the <item> of the <channel> of the <rss>.

Comment: Show your XML parsing code.

Comment: @RickFalck http://pastebin.com/QwajPhxU

Comment: @RickFalck do tell me if you need the classes that store the xml ( That is RSS,Channel,Item) as well. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Oops.  I didn't know you were using some third party thing.  I have no idea.  Sorry.